# Target filesystem doesn't have requested /lib/systemd/systemd

Tags: debian, boot, hard-disk, systemd

I have been using `systemd` for about a month without any problems on my Debian Jessie. I installed it according to the Debian [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd#Installation). But all of a sudden today I got this error:

[image: ss of error]

*Original: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUkMl.jpg*

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you sure it's not your hard disk?

Comment: That looks a lot more like a physical disk problem (or your disk controller) than a software issue.

Comment: Agreed it looks like your HDD is dying/failing.

Comment: I would immediately run something like HDAT2 or Spinrite on the HDDs. See my prior A's: http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hdat2

Comment: here is a more vertical picture of the errors: http://i.imgur.com/MHqvI86.jpg (excuse the quality)

Comment: Yes you were correct. The disk is dying. I've been able to access it via live cd and now I'm copying files off of it(though dead show). should I delete this question or leave it as a cautionary tale?

Comment: I would leave it. Users might stumble on it when they google for the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of `systemd` is the point where the system gave up because there was no more way to recover. When you see a series of errors, you need to go backward until you hit the root cause.

The lack of `systemd` was due to an inability to mount the root filesystem.

```
mount: mounting … on /root failed: invalid argument
```

This inability to mount was due to the block device containing the root filesystem (which here is identified by a UUID) not being available.

It is highly likely that the block device in question is a partition on the disk concerned by the error messages immediately above. A series of messages like

```
end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, …
```

is a bad sign about the disk that is identified as `/dev/sdc`. The CPU detects that a disk drive is present isn't able to read data from the drive. The cable or the drive is failing (or, a lot less likely because you'd have noticed before, the driver is buggy).